# Нужно решить один момент в задаче, какой оператор использовать

Tags: c#, csharpcodeprovider

Смотрите тут такая вот ситуация :

Пользоваетель вводит свое локальное время по частям , первый - час , второя - минута , третий - секунда. написал вот вот в таком вот формате : [image: Прог]
Сейчас хочу проверить какие данные ввел пользователь , если показатель часика меньше 0 или больше или равно 24 то надо чтобы цикл  h = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());  повторялось. написал роудмеп вот таким вот образом : 
[image: прог]

никак не решил какой оператор использовать 
пробовал if вот таким вот образом : [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
если иф выдает тру то обычно продолжает , если выдает фолс продолжает с тем же введенным. return h; пробовал прописать в операторе иф но не работает и это очевино , h вне видимости if а. прошу подскажте что и как.

Comment: Почитайте главу «циклы» в книге по C#.

Comment: Прочту обязательно.

Comment: Замените в вопросе картинки кодом как текст.

Comment: Вам скорее всего нужен ```while``` или ```do-while```

Comment: Использовал do-while таким образом

do {
                Console.WriteLine("err try again");               
            } while (h < 0 || h >25 ); 

Не получилось

так же сделал вот так так :do {
                h = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
                if (h < 0 || h >25) {
                Console.WriteLine("err try again"); 
                    }
            } while (h== true ); 

проблема та же

Answer (score 0):

Используйте циклы с условием, а выходите из них только тогда, когда пользователь введет, наконец, правильное число. Для этих целей можно использовать ключевое слово **break**. Здесь я вдобавок обернул всё в try/catch, чтобы предусмотреть ситуацию, если пользователь введёт не числовое значение.

```
while (true)
{
        try
        {
            h = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (h > 0 && h < 24) 
                break;  //нас всё устраивает, выходим из while
            else 
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong number!! Enter again");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"error:{ex.Message}!! Enter again");
        }                
}
```

Comment: Вместо того, чтобы ловить исключение, можно было бы использовать `int.TryParse`.